# Track in real time all new published questions regardless of which tag is used (I want to help edit new questions with formatting errors)

Tags: discussion, questions, api

I'm trying to reproduce something like [realtime found on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) but only with the new Stack Overflow questions.

I searched the existing questions, but I didn't find one that specifically answers the case **all tags**.

I tried the following via code, but browsers don't have an option that can [opening a new unfocused tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201787/opening-a-new-unfocused-tab-in-chrome-or-firefox-with-python-on-windows-os-or-s), so I had to give up (the pages would be opening over the one I'm looking at, so if I were editing one, I'd get totally lost and get in the way rather than help).

Step by step code:

1. accesses the unanswered questions in the API and sorts according to the hour of publication
2. checks if the question is already saved to a local csv file
3. opens new questions url in a new browser tab

```python
import feedparser
from time import sleep
import sys
import requests
import webbrowser
from datetime import datetime, time
import pandas as pd

with open('my_user_agent.txt') as f:
    my_user_agent = f.read()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': my_user_agent
    }
key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
accessToken = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA'

def main():
    while True:
        repository = 'stackoverflow_rss'
        csv_file = f'{repository}.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        date_today = round(datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow().date(), time(0,0,0)).timestamp())
        url = f"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/no-answers?pagesize=30&fromdate={date_today}&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&access_token=" + accessToken + "&key=" + key
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30).json()
        questions = response['items']
        for question in questions:
            sof = question['link']
            if (len(df[df['url'] == sof]) == 0) and not ('last_edit_date' in question):
                webbrowser.open(sof, new=0, autoraise=False)
                with open(f'{repository}.csv','a') as fd:
                    fd.write(sof + '\n')

        for remaining in range(10, 0, -1):
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write('Next run in {:2d} seconds'.format(remaining))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r                               ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Currently, I follow tags that I may be able to answer, but in my spare time I wanted to open a page open to follow in real time all the questions posted like this:

[image]

With these filters and sort,

[image]

I accessed the API and collected all existing tags, but there is a character limit in the search bar, so it doesn't accept putting all tags.

Is there a way to keep track of all tags?

Comment: Why not use the [first questions review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/)?

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson because it won't cover all questions (only first question) and I find it less interactive than clicking when there are new questions on the button, I feel more comfortable that way, but I'll use it. The question is more out of curiosity, I tried putting ```-[blablabla]``` to remove this tag and pull all the others, but it doesn't generate the ```X new questions button```.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://stackapps.com/questions/7267/how-to-get-new-questions-continuously

Comment: Tips: 1. Save a custom filter. It seems to bypass the character limit Or it's at least higher. 2. Use wildcards. For example `[google-*]`

Comment: Hi @rene I added in my question a code that I tried to create, but I had to give up, there is the reason for giving up next to the link of the question and the answers I received.

Comment: Hi @VLAZ Very good this tip, I just tried to do it with all of them but the page gets so big that the save button disappears. Haha. I'll readjust with your wildcards tip!

Comment: You can also save multiple custom filters. Might make more sense, if you want to split into different areas. E.g. one filter for google tags and other technologies.

Comment: *"[about the first post queue] because it won't cover all questions"* - Why does that matter? You can't unilaterally edit posts anyway, so your ability to edit is massively hindered and you won't be _able_ to cover all questions.

Comment: Hi @NickstandswithUkraine as I said my idea is to use the free time between one task and another daily, I won't spend hours editing, only just a few spare minutes during the day, so being able to look at several in a short space of time would be useful for me, it would entertain me and I could help with the formatting. (I asked more as a curiosity about there being a way or trick, not as something really necessary)

Comment: Perhaps add the (short) gist of the code *before* it is listed? E.g., it is not clear until the end whether it parses an [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed or is using the Stack Exchange API.

Comment: Related: *[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its)*

Comment: And it is not supported by an RSS feed? I tried `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds` (in [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird)'s built-in RSS feed reader). The default title is *"Recent Questions - Stack Overflow"* though it is not clear what that is ("hot questions"? - whatever that is or was).

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen the code does this: it accesses the unanswered questions in the API and sorts according to the time of publication, those that have not yet been saved to a local csv file, are opened in new browser tabs. The problem is that browsers don't have options via code to open tabs in the background (unfocused), so if I'm looking at a page, the code will open new tabs one on top of the other in the foreground and the one I look gets lost in the middle of the others. (the idea would be to look, see if I had something to edit, if not, I would close and look at the next one and so on)

Comment: @Digital Farmer: So *part* of the gist is to automate the opening of new tabs, instead of having to do it manually?

Comment: Exactly @PeterMortensen ! But the problem is on Windows (using Python) the new tabs overlap the active tab, this is quite annoying (I need to open a feature request in Chrome and Firefox about this).

Comment: @Digital Farmer: Tabs can ***moved / rearranged*** with *Shift + Ctrl + PgDn* and *Shift + Ctrl + PgUp*. The *current* tab (that is to be moved) can be ***changed*** with *Shift + Ctrl + Tab* and *Ctrl + Tab*. (I have all four on my macro keyboard.) You may be able to send those using [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) or similar (I don't know about Python). (I once used AutoIt to automate otherwise repetitive manual steps for the typical workflow related to developing a .NET application on Windows with Visual Studio, including some user startup procedures in the application.)

Comment: Or in other words, you can open a new tab ***to the left*** by opening it, move it to the left with *Shift + Ctrl + PgUp*, and switch back to the original tab with *Ctrl + Tab*. (I have a macro key on my macro keyboard that uses that for the link under the cursor (using a right mouse click by the macro keyboard as the first action).)

Comment: It does require ***disabling*** option *"Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order"* in Firefox (it is enabled by default). Hamburger menu (upper right) → *"Settings"* → *"General"* (left panel) → section *"Tab"* (second section).

Comment: Hum..., the whole "*Enterprise*" doesn't sound *very useful* to me @OP as you don't have 2k+_Rep, and you'll be clogging the 'Edit'-Queue which is already always full (+ have to wait for 24h-48h before your Edits get approved...), but anyway, the 'Tab Open' Func you want could easily be done using the Tool/Tag (for Web-Automation) I answer on this Site... Link to the [iMacros Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info) (which contains all Info)... (But New Tabs always get opened to the Right of Current_Tab...)

Comment: @DigitalFarmer: "*so being able to look at several in a short space of time would be useful for me, it would entertain me and I could help with the formatting.*" Then it doesn't really matter if the questions are the absolute *newest*, does it? It only matters if they're new to you. Also, please don't do this. We don't need people making trivial edits to formatting and the like. We need people reviewing questions for their quality, not sprucing them up.

Comment: Opening a new tab/window which isn't focused can be done using a userscript (using `GM_openInTab()`/`GM.openInTab()`) and/or a browser extension.

Comment: Hi @NicolBolas I'm sorry but saying that you don't want people "sprucing" the questions is a little ironic and unnecessary, you know why? Correctly formatted questions give a much easier view of the cases for those who read and try to help, so if what I can help with is this, why couldn't I? But if this is the thinking of the community, ask to remove the text that appears from the edit examples box because it contains "improved formatting", if don't want them to do that, then it's better not to leave it as a example of using the edit option.

Comment: HI @Makyen I'm analyzing the option to do it in the Chrome console, it seemed like a good option.

Answer (score 5):

> I wanted to open a page open to follow in real time all the questions posted like this:

Have you ever used an SE site other than SO? Notice that the front page of those sites will give a prompt that there are new questions?

Notice that Stack Overflow's main page *doesn't* do this?

There's a reason for that. The sheer volume of questions SO gets on a *per-minute* basis is staggering. You really *do not* want a real-time flow of questions. That update prompt would always be there, even immediately after you clicked one, because there are *always* new questions.

If you really, *really* want to see all of the questions, just [refresh this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest). It won't be updated in real-time because that's not practical at SO scale. So that's the best you're going to get.

Comment: In fact, the only site that does not appear in the new questions box is the OS, I fully understand the non-use of this option and in fact they are 100% correct in keeping it without it, I fully agree with you on these points!

Comment: This is correct. As far as I'm aware, there's *nothing* available from SE which provides push notifications of a complete set of new or active questions on SO. As you mention, that information *is* available for every other site through the SE WebSocket. The main SE `155-questions-active` WebSocket does contain *some* of the active questions on SO, but it's *definitely* not all of them. SmokeDetector achieves knowing about all new/active SO questions, but has to do so via polling for new/active questions, rather than relying upon notifications.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I wrote "in fact" when I really meant "That's a fact!", agreeing with him and saying that he was perfect in the answear.